# socat TCP server bidirectional using sleep, non-interactive client returns without response. Server reports: I/O error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tcp, netcat, socat

I have the following TCP server:

```bash
socat TCP-LISTEN:10000,fork,reuseaddr SYSTEM:'read -r msg && sleep 3 && echo "OK"'
```

When I execute (interactive mode):

```bash
socat - TCP:localhost:10000
> some text here [ENTER]
```

It will return "OK" after 3 seconds (as expected)

However, I need to do it non-interactive:

```bash
response=$(echo "some text" | socat - TCP:localhost:10000)
```

But it returns immediately without response and the server reports after 3 seconds `echo: I/O error` (as the client is no longer connected).

If I remove "sleep 3" from the server, it works fine, but I need the "sleep" to work (as I'm actually executing a command that may sleep until it gets some response from another server).

How can it be fixed?

- Using Ubuntu 22.04
- It doesn't need to use `socat` as client
- Ultimately the server and the client will be on different servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socat works with half close of sockets. That means, when it receives EOF (shutdown) on one address (in your case the TCP connection) it shuts down the write channel of the second address and gives it per default only 0.5 seconds until it closes the connection completely.

Thus you can get the I/O error even in interactive mode when you press ^D before the 3s have passed.

Possible solutions are:

Defer EOF on client:

```
response=$( { echo "some text"; sleep 4; } | socat - TCP:localhost:10000)
```

Or increase half close timeout on both processes:

```
socat -t 3.1 TCP-LISTEN:10000,fork,reuseaddr SYSTEM:'read -r msg && sleep 3 && echo "OK"'

response=$(echo "some text" | socat -t 3.1 - TCP:localhost:10000)
```

Comment: It works. So in summary, I needed to add `-t NUM` for both (client and server) in order this to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `nc` works as expected:

```bash
echo "message" | nc localhost 10000
```

If someone can explain why `socat` doesn't work the same or how to make it work with `socat`, I will accept that answer.